# I modified my php.ini file and now I cannot log onto the server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I modified the php.ini file in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini because I wanted to increase my phpmyadmin limit. I did this using Ubuntu terminal.

The settings initially were:

```
upload_max_filesize:1000M
post_max_limit:500M
memory_limit: -1
```

I changed it to:

```
upload_max_filesize:100M
post_max_limit:100M
memory_limit: 128M
```

I restarted Apache and now I am getting this error:

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.

I tried changing the values back to the way they were in Ubuntu but it still does not work.

I cannot post any files as I am working for a client.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Did you also change anything in your virtualhost?

Comment: Notice `cli`.  That's not the `php.ini` that the webserver uses, so you changed something else.

Comment: No. I didn't change anything else.

Comment: I also made changed to /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and that didn't mess up anything. I applied changes to that file multiple times but nothing happened. As soon as I made change to this php.ini file. everything stopped working

Comment: The error sounds like a simple htauth password is in effect. Is there an `.htaccess` file in the doc root specifying a password file? What you changed doesn't look like it would upset this, so your configuration may have been fragile to begin with, and needed fixing anyway.

Comment: yes, there is a .htaccess file in the root directory but I don't see a password file specified in it

Comment: Possible cause: You changed something hours or maybe even days or week ago, but changes applied when restarting the server. Think back; did you change anything before that? Also, on the basicauth-matter, it's maybe easier to look for a .htpasswd file.